# DOMContentLoaded handler with rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 5 and I'm trying to implement the following in a `.js` file under the `assets/javascript` folder. But for some reason its not working at all. I'm kind of guessing that the content needs to be wrapped with aDOMContentLoaded handler, but not sure how to do it.

Any ideas on how I can wrap the javacontent of that file in a DOMContentLoaded handler?

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//=require jquery
//=require jquery_ujs
//=require jquery.turbolinks
//=require turbolinks-compatibility
//=require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  }
});
```

Although using a cross-browser compatible solution such as [jQuery.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) might be prudent.

Additionally if you are using turbolinks you should hook into its `"turbolinks:load"` event instead (as in 
Sebastián Palma´s answer) as `DOMContentLoaded` is not fired when turbolinks replaces the page content.

Comment: I'm using this `<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>` and its not working @max.